# Calling both array key and value from an array separately in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I don't want to use any `foreach` or `while` loop. I have an array like the following:

```
$q5_value = array( 
    "Essentialto our Business " => "$avg_5_1",
    "promising but not  yet optimized" => "$avg_5_2" , 
    "Somewhat effectiv" => "$avg_5_3",
    "we're curious, but haven't tried these yet" => "$avg_5_4",
    "Not very effective" => "$avg_5_5",
    "We still have alot to figure out about this" => "$avg_5_6",                 
    "Not worth the effort" => "$avg_5_7"
); 

rsort($q5_value);
```

Now when I call

```
echo $q5_value[0];
```

this is showing me the largest integer compared among the variables. I want to show the strings from the left side too. Any help?

Comment: Do you have all those variables like $avg_5_1?

Comment: @sectus yes. they all are integers

Comment: So, remove quotes around it.

Comment: You're looking for [`arsort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php). Since this preserves the index association, you'll have to use [`current`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php) or `reset` to get the first value since there'll be no other way to determine the first element in the array.

Comment: Noting helps. thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with "rsort".  rsort will strip out the keys during its sorting process.  You should be using "arsort" to keep the existing keys.

Assuming your [0] array element is sorted properly, you can use the key() function to get the key.

```html
arsort($q5_value);
print key($q5_value). " | ". $q5_value[0];
```